# IE7 getting null or object value in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form with hidden fields with name.In javascript I am getting the form hidden value using following expression

`document.getElementById('form-name').hidden-input-name.value`.

In all browsers it is working fine except IE7.In IE7,I am getting value as null or not an object for the above expression.
Can anyone help me please.Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of ".hidden-input-name" before .value? It should works without it, with a note: your element has id="form-name" not only name="form-name".

Comment: @MuhammadAlvin: He's probably using something like `<form id='form-name'><input type='hidden' name='hidden-input-name'/>...</form>`.

Comment: @Zeta oh, i understand now. I think, adding id="something" in the <input> then retrieve its value by document.getElementById('something').value is easier. And i never encounter any problem personally.

Comment: @MuhammadAlvin:zeta is right.I have the form with hidden fields like that.It is alerting the message as document.getElementByid('form-name').hidden-input-name.value is null or object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any other element with attribute `name = "form-name"` because older versions of IE didn't distinguish b/w `id="" and name=""`

Comment: Thank you..It was issue of having the same form-name

Answer (score 0):

The element name is not a valid JavaScript identifier, so you must use such syntax instead:

```
var value = document.getElementById('form-name').elements("hidden-input-name").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

untested but how about trying:

```
document.getElementById('form-name')["hidden-input-name"].value
```